# Insert batch statement difference between two queries

Tags: sql, questdb

Is there any difference between these two queries:

```
create table tab(value int, ts timestamp) timestamp(ts) 

-- q1:
insert batch 2 into tab values(1, systimestamp()),(2, systimestamp())

-- q2:
insert batch 2 into tab select cast(x as int),systimestamp()  from long_sequence(2)
```

Should they be equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

In **q1** batch 2 has no effect.
In **q2** batch 2 will delay commit until two insert statements have been seen.